# Use same column in a SQL Query twice

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, datagrid

I'm writing sql query where I want to use the same column twice in datagrid view.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT ElectricityMachinePanelDetails.MachineDescription AS "Machine Name",
       ReadingValue AS "Last Day Meter Reading" 
FROM ElectricityDailyMeterReadingDetails
INNER JOIN ElectricityMachinePanelDetails ON ElectricityMachinePanelDetails.MachinePanelID = ElectricityDailyMeterReadingDetails.MachinePanelID
INNER JOIN ReadingTypesDetails ON ElectricityDailyMeterReadingDetails.ReadingTypeID = ReadingTypesDetails.ReadingTypeID 
WHERE ReadingCategoryID = 'RC001' AND 
      ReadingTypesDetails.ReadingTypeID = 'RT001'
```

How can I use column name `ReadingValue` twice in the datagrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use it twice, if the datagridview allows doublename im not sure. Otherwise just give it another name "Last Day Meter Reading Copy".

```
Select 
ElectricityMachinePanelDetails.MachineDescription AS "Machine Name",
ReadingValue AS "Last Day Meter Reading",
ReadingValue AS "Last Day Meter Copy"
from ElectricityDailyMeterReadingDetails
INNER JOIN ElectricityMachinePanelDetails on ElectricityMachinePanelDetails.MachinePanelID = ElectricityDailyMeterReadingDetails.MachinePanelID
INNER JOIN ReadingTypesDetails ON ElectricityDailyMeterReadingDetails.ReadingTypeID = ReadingTypesDetails.ReadingTypeID where ReadingCategoryID = 'RC001' AND ReadingTypesDetails.ReadingTypeID = 'RT001'
```

In MSSQL you cannot have the same column name twice i think. But in MySQL its fine.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, use aliases instead of table names in joins. So your query could be more readable.

```
select
    empd.MachineDescription as "Machine Name",
    rtd.ReadingValue AS "Last Day Meter Reading"
from ElectricityDailyMeterReadingDetails as edmrd
    inner join ElectricityMachinePanelDetails as empd on empd.MachinePanelID = edmrd.MachinePanelID
    inner join ReadingTypesDetails as rtd on rtd.ReadingTypeID  = edmrd.ReadingTypeID
where
    rtd.ReadingCategoryID = 'RC001' and
    rtd.ReadingTypesDetails.ReadingTypeID = 'RT001'
```

If you want to join ReadingTypesDetails twice, you can easily do this:

```
select
    empd.MachineDescription as "Machine Name",
    rtd.ReadingValue as "Last Day Meter Reading",
    rtd2.ReadingValue as "Another Reading"
from ElectricityDailyMeterReadingDetails as edmrd
    inner join ElectricityMachinePanelDetails as empd on empd.MachinePanelID = edmrd.MachinePanelID
    inner join ReadingTypesDetails as rtd on rtd.ReadingTypeID  = edmrd.ReadingTypeID
    inner join ReadingTypesDetails as rtd2 on rtd2.ReadingTypeID  = edmrd.ReadingTypeID
where
    rtd.ReadingCategoryID = 'RC001' and
    rtd.ReadingTypesDetails.ReadingTypeID = 'RT001' and
    --rtd2.ReadingCategoryID = '????' and
    --rtd2.ReadingTypesDetails.ReadingTypeID = '????' and
```

Comment: Its not needed to join the table twice. Can simply use rtd.ReadingValue twice.

Comment: @KayNelson I assume that OP knows how to use value from same table twice, but didn't know how to join same table twice. Don't know why he will need absolute same value twice.